# changing webview agent in c#-metro

Tags: c#-4.0, webview, windows-phone-8.1, microsoft-metro

hi guys im creating a metro app for my lumia 930 (windows 8.1) that it has a webview .
Questions :
1. how to change webview agent, i mean how to show desktop version of website?
2. how to allow download and upload in webview?

TNX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i just found something that works and answered the first question.

add this to your header

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

and add this to your class

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(int dwOption, string pBuffer, int dwBufferLength, int dwReserved);

    const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT = 0x10000001;
    public void ChangeUserAgent(string Agent)
    {
        UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, Agent, Agent.Length, 0);
    }
```

and add this before navigating to url

```
ChangeUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0");
```

now its done . but the second question remains :|

sources:
[Change user agent in WP8.1 WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228722/change-user-agent-in-wp8-1-webview?rq=1)
   and
[Want to load desktop version in my webview using uastring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309796/want-to-load-desktop-version-in-my-webview-using-uastring)

Comment: this will fail certification. see reference