# Rendering MathJax in Windows Phone App WebView creates Certification issue

Tags: windows-phone-8, webview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, mathjax

I need to render mathematical equations in a WebView with the help of MathJax. WebView in mobile version doesn't support mathjax that's why I changed the user agent of the webview following [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25229068/1067326).

Math equations are perfectly showed in my device(Lumia 820) when the app is built with debug version. But when I try to publish the app in windows store it says following error message:

> This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=UrlMkSetSessionOption. Module=urlmon.dll.
>   File=DurbinWin.WindowsPhone.exe.

Is there any way to display mathjax that doesn't creates certification issues?

Comment: Are you including your own copy of MathJax? There's also a bug in MathJax that will be fixed in the next release https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1085 that might be related.

Comment: I'm retrieving MathJax from their server. And I guess the problem is not with MathJax, it perfectly works in my device as I stated, the problem is the API that is used to change the user agent of WebView is not supported by Windows Store.

Comment: One more thing to point out: is MathJax supposed to work with windows phone internet explorer in `Mobile Version`? I browsed mathjax.org with windows phone internet explorer, it didn't work in `Mobile Version` but worked in `Desktop Version`. That's why I changed the user agent of `Webview` to render like Desktop Version.

Comment: You might want to try shipping a slim copy. There's a simple grunt file on github to slim it down. The issue might come from different policies for remote scripts. You can then also try to cherry-pick the fix for that UA detection bug on our end.

Comment: http://www.learnhive.net/blog/2012/10/tutorial-how-to-port-mathjax-to-windows-8-store-applications/   on this link they have mentioned why yous app fails certification if you use MathMl. Also can you elaborate how you achieved this rendering, I need to know it !